# Are these trigonometric expressions for the ceiling and floor functions correct?

Tags: trigonometry, pi, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I believe that I have found a trigonometric expression for both the ceiling and floor function, and I seek confirmation that it is, indeed, correct.

**Update.**

$$\begin{align}
\lfloor x \rfloor &= x - \frac12+f(x) \\[4pt] 
\lceil  x \rceil  &= x + \frac12+g(x)
\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}
\frac12, & x\in\Bbb{Z} \\[4pt]
0, &x=\frac12n, n\in\Bbb{Z} \\[4pt]
\frac1\pi \tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x)), &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\[10pt]
g(x) &= \begin{cases}
-\frac12, & x\in\Bbb{Z} \\[4pt]
0, &x=\frac12n, n\in\Bbb{Z} \\[4pt]
\frac1\pi \tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x)), &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Comment: your function is not defined for integer

Comment: Why is that, @stity?

Comment: Because $\tan$ of integer multiples of $\pi$ is $0$ so $\cot$ is undefined at these points.

Comment: Ah, of course! @SamWeatherhog

Comment: That might not be a problem, if Taylor can adduce situations under which these expressions may be "of some use."  It may be, for instance, that it would only be used for some application where $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: Just define $f(x)=\arctan(\cot(\pi x))/\pi$ for $x\not\in\mathbb Z$ and $f(x)=1/2$ for $x\in\mathbb Z$ and then use that $f$ in your formula for floor.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I am not sure what you mean, Gregory.

Comment: @BrianTung I do hope that it may be useful in some way. :)

Comment: @Taylor yes $\lim_{x\to \infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{pi}{2}$. Gregory is saying that you make your function $x-\frac{1}{2}+f(x)$ where $f$ is defined as in his comment

Comment: @SamWeatherhog Ah, I see! Perfect. :)

Comment: @Taylor I mean define $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \arctan(\cot(\pi x))/\pi, & x\not\in\mathbb Z\\ 1/2, & x\in\mathbb Z\end{array}\right.$.
Then
$\lfloor{x}\rfloor = x - \frac{1}{2} + f(x)$ $\forall x$.

Comment: Note the identity $\tan(\pi/2-x)=\cot(x)$ just gives you zero when you plug in for $\cot(\pi*x)$. This formula depends on what value you take for $\arctan$

Comment: @SamWeatherhog I am afraid I do not understand.

Comment: @Taylor You have to modify $f$ for the floor case to be $-1/2$ for $x\in\mathbb Z$, otherwise it gives you $x+1$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Would that not give you $x - 1$?

Comment: Taylor, I assume @GregoryGrant meant ceiling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you have the identity $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cot(x)$. Using this, your formula for the floor function is:

$$
\begin{split} \lfloor x \rfloor &= x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi\cdot x\right)\right)}{\pi} \\ &=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi\cdot x+n\pi}{\pi}, \text{ for }n\in\mathbb{Z} \\ &=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-x+n \\ &=n \end{split}
$$

Then there is some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=\lfloor x \rfloor$. If, as usual, you insist that $-\pi\le \arctan(x) \le \pi$ this then forces:

$$
\begin{split} && -1\le \frac{1}{2}-x+n \le 1 \\ &\implies& -\frac{3}{2}\le n-x \le \frac{1}{2} \\ &\implies& x-\frac{3}{2} \le n \le x+\frac{1}{2} \end{split}
$$

So the value for $n$ is close to $\lfloor x \rfloor$. I'm not sure how computers choose which value to pick for $\arctan$ but it appears to always pick the right one for your formula to work. I'm not sure it would be a good idea to use this formula in your work unless you know which value of $\arctan$ to pick to ensure that you get the right answer.

Comment: Does that mean that the formula is correct, then?

Comment: It will be correct for some value of $\arctan$ but $\arctan$ is multiple valued so then you're just choosing the value of $\arctan$ that makes the formula work. For example, if $x=1.6$ then $\arctan(\cot(\pi*x))$ could be $-0.3142$ (which makes the formula work) or you could choose $-3.4558$ and this value will not make the formula work.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the single-valued $\arctan$, i.e. $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \arctan(x) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, which is what all computer languages I've seen use, this works perfectly fine.

Proof:

Let $x = s(a + b)$, where $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 \leq b < 1$ and $s \in \{-1,1\}$. We can call $a$ the absolute integer part, $b$ the absolute fractional part, and $s$ is $x$'s sign.

Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\arctan(\cot(\pi x))}{\pi}
&= \frac{\arctan(\cot(\pi s(a + b)))}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\arctan(s\cdot\cot(\pi a + \pi b)))}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\arctan(s\cdot\cot(\pi b))}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\arctan(s\cdot\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi b))}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\arctan(s\cdot\tan(\pi(\frac{1}{2} - b)))}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi s(\frac{1}{2} - b)))}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= \frac{\pi s(\frac{1}{2} - b)}{\pi}\\[1em]
&= s\bigg(\frac{1}{2} - b\bigg)\\[1em]
\end{align*}
$$

Note that we can assert that $\arctan(\tan(\pi s(\frac{1}{2} - b)) = \pi s(\frac{1}{2} - b)$ without issues only because

$$
\begin{alignat*}{5}
0           && \quad \leq &&  b \quad && < \quad &&  1 &&\implies\\[0.5em]
0           && \quad \geq && -b \quad && > \quad && -1 &&\implies\\[0.5em]
\frac{1}{2} && \quad \geq && \quad \frac{1}{2} - b  \quad && > \quad && -\frac{1}{2} &&\implies\\[0.5em]
\frac{\pi}{2} && \quad \geq &&\ \ \ \pi\Bigg(\frac{1}{2} - b\Bigg) \quad && > \quad && -\frac{\pi}{2} &&\\
\end{alignat*}
$$

$\arctan(\tan(x)) = x$ only holds for $x$ in that range. For example, $\arctan(\tan(x)) = x - \pi$ if $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi$.

With that said...
$$
\begin{align*}
\lfloor x \rfloor &= x - \frac{1}{2} + s\bigg(\frac{1}{2} - b\bigg)\\[0.5em]
&= s(a + b) - \frac{1 - s}{2} - sb\\[0.5em]
&= s(a + b - b) - \frac{1 - s}{2}\\[0.5em]
&= sa - \frac{1 - s}{2}\\[0.5em]
\end{align*}
$$

If $s=1$, $\lfloor x\rfloor = a - \frac{1 - 1}{2} = a$.

If $s=-1$, $\lfloor x\rfloor = -a - \frac{1 + 1}{2} = -a - 1 = -(a + 1)$.

This works because $\lfloor \pm y.uwv \rfloor$ is y if the number is positive, and $-(y + 1)$ if the number is negative. e.g. $\lfloor 1.2\rfloor = 1$ but $\lfloor -1.2\rfloor = -2$.

Proving that your $ceil$ function works should go about the same way.

I realize I am three years late to this but I initially was going to post my own trigonometric floor:

$$
\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \text{frac}(x)\\[1.4em]
%
\text{frac}(x) = \text{sgn}\Big(\sin(2\pi x)\Big)\Bigg( \frac{\cos^{-1}(\cos(2\pi x))}{2\pi} - \frac{1}{2} \Bigg) + \frac{1}{2}\\[1.4em]
%
\text{sgn}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{\cot^{-1}(x) - \cot^{-1}(-x)}{\big|\cot^{-1}(x)\big|}\Bigg)
$$

But yours seems a bit simpler.

Comment: This is excellent and much better defined, thank you for sharing +1