# Modulo operation

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic

I believe that I have found a trigonometric expression for the modulo operation, and I was wondering if it could be confirmed, and whether or not it would have any application.

$$a\pmod{b} = \frac{b}{2} - m(x)$$

$$m(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{b}{2} & \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Z} \\
0 & \frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{2}n, n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\frac{b \arctan{\left(\cot{\left(\frac{a}{b}\pi\right)}\right)}}{\pi} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What you have seems to be a modulo operation, not because I've checked it, but because $\arctan(\tan x)$ is the modulo $\pi$ operation where it is defined (finding a value between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ instead of $0$ and $\pi$).

Comment: @Arthur Ah, nice!

Comment: Similar: [Are these trigonometric expressions for the ceiling and floor functions correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545006/318073).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression looks correct. Perhaps the expression can be simplified if you use arccot instead of arctan.

To find a useful application you would need a context where trigonometric functions and their inverses are easier to compute than modular arithmetic.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's a related discussion: [Representation of $x \bmod a$ with Trigonometric Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285017/representation-of-x-bmod-a-with-trigonometric-functions)
that has some additional insights. These threads could be merged.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1933866)